# how to change spotlight name showed of my results?

Tags: ios, corespotlight

I want to change the  section name   belong to my app when users do the spotlight ,i have tried to change the   bundledisplayname   and bundlename  it just changed the  name showed  on the  screen ,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `CFBundleDisplayName`